# OS X - browse entire photos library from an ipad or iPhone

Tags: ios

There is an app that allows you to browse your entire OS X photos.app library called photoscope (http://photoscopeapp.com).  I'm trying to find other better apps that allow you to browse your library from iphone/ipad.

Does anyone know of other apps.  Tried alternativeto.net but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a number of apps that could fit, if I understand your question correctly. Have a look at:

- [Photo Album - Private Organizer with Slideshows](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/photo-album-smart-organizer/id496799120?mt=8): for both iPhone and iPad, free but has in app purchases, can import unlimited number of photos and organize them into albums, set pin, etc.
- [Slidebox - Photo Manager & Album Organizer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slidebox-photo-manager-album-organizer/id984305203?mt=8): for both iPhone and iPad, free but has in app purchases, synced to your iOS Photo library, works with iCloud Photo Library, etc.
- [MyPics - A Powerful Photo Album](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mypics-a-powerful-photo-album/id504793067?mt=8): for both iPhone and iPad, free but has in app purchases, import photos, edit photos, create albums, etc.

Check them out, maybe one of them can work for you.

Comment: thank you for the reply.  But i guess i should be more specific.  I would like to be able to stream/accees off my mac the entire contents of my Photos library... similar to the concept above.  where the app i mentioned as a "helper" on the computer and a companion IOS app that allows to access all the photos and videos and albums etc..  I don't want to store library on any cloud services.